# How to delete an entry in a cache

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I am using Spring cache. I would like to delete a single entry within the cache if a particular condition is met in due time.

```
   @Cacheable(value = "statusEligibility", key = "#customerId")
   @GetMapping
   public CustomerStatusDTO getCustomerStatus(@PathVariable String customerId) {

  Customer customer = cusomterPort.getAccount(customerId);
  Status status = service.getStatus(customer);

  //Logic:
  //If status equals required then forward call to service to assert it. then delete the account from cache
  //else return not_required
  if (status.equals(Cons.REQUIRED)) {
     /.../
  } else {
     /.../
  }
```

}

How would I be able to delete the customer object from the cache if it fulfils the condition in the if statement?

Comment: Have you tried `private final @Autowired CacheManager manager` with `manager.getCache("cacheName").evict(key);` called in the method?

Comment: I created a method annotated with cacheevict with the relevent value and key in them. I've written a unit test but it seems to not be going through the cache

Answer (score 1):

First, have a look at the `@CacheEvict` annotation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-evict)

Then, have a look at "*conditional*" caching:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-condition

`@CacheEvict` has many of the same attributes as `@Cacheable`:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/CacheEvict.html

Hope this helps!